# How do I merge two C codes into one?

Tags: c

I wrote four pieces of code in C to calculate some physical properties (specific heat, density, etc) of water as a function of temperature. They compile and work just fine but I want to put them into a single file so to have only one exe. When I press 1 I want the code to return the specific heat value, when I press 2 return the density value and so on.

I know I have to define 4 functions for each property and also I think this code is necessary:

```
int choice;

printf("Press 1 to compute specific heat.\n");
printf("Press 2 to compute density.\n");
printf("Press 3 to compute thermal conductivity.\n");
printf("Press 4 to compute viscosity.\n");
printf("Press 5 to exit.\n");
printf("Enter your choice\n");
scanf("%d",&choice);

if (choice == 1)
{
execute the specific heat function;
}

if (choice == 2)
{
execute the density function;
}

if (choice == 3)
{
execute the thermal conductivity function;
}

if (choice == 4)
{
execute the viscosity function;
}

if (choice == 5)
exit(0);
```

Below are the pieces of code I want to merge. I attached only two because if I can do it with 2 than I can do it with 4.

specific heat part:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <math.h>

int main()
{    
    float T, cp1, cp2, cp3, cp4, cp5, cp6, cp7, cp8;                     /*variables */  

    printf( "Enter temperature in Kelvin (range 280-900 K)\n" );  /* Asks for temperature */
    scanf( "%f", &T );

    cp1=1.67662377469456E-11*pow(T,6.)-4.1197828092268E-08*pow(T,5.)+0.0000418869586791152*pow(T,4.)-0.0225003443462658*pow(T,3.)+6.72987826198519*pow(T,2.)-1062.18721205927*T+73195.8387080729;
    cp2=0.00525246395569212*pow(T,4.)-12.9485474717992*pow(T,3.)+11970.600895997*pow(T,2.)-4918448.82178862*T+757825839.152518;
    cp3=6.63085194968153*pow(T,4.)-17170.4000395659*pow(T,3.)+16673480.6519115*pow(T,2.)-7196031423.69135*T+1164647463146.08;
    cp4=-68.0819524480029*pow(T,5.)+222554.556013276*pow(T,4.)-291004129.724188*pow(T,3.)+190252342532.153*pow(T,2.)-62191220562433.3*T+8131793672657510;
    cp5=9974.74747475981*pow(T,3.)-19674382.9004572*pow(T,2.)+12935329616.4157*T-2834856258114.32;
    cp6=-4.14962557364299E-07*pow(T,6.)+0.000462300031790556*pow(T,5.)-0.0310330512189478*pow(T,4.)+62.8598088326175*pow(T,3.)-189691.032172151*pow(T,2.)+77129922.3433911*T-4056849697.67083;
    cp7=1.47773054803578E-08*pow(T,6.)-0.0000239186385308144*pow(T,5.)+0.00563616606939476*pow(T,4.)+1.50391266948934*pow(T,3.)+9118.7111011683*pow(T,2.)-8897122.07353999*T+2172208386.41784;
    cp8=-4.6626284146362E-08*pow(T,5.)+0.000192659539297423*pow(T,4.)-0.318404373982708*pow(T,3.)+263.141418952148*pow(T,2.)-108775.736711323*T+18001673.992402;


    if (T>=280. && T<=599.9f) {                     /* 1st temp range*/ 
        printf ("1st range Cp= %.6f J/kgK",cp1);                    /* returns cp1 */
    }
    else if (T>599.9 && T<=646.8) {            /* 2nd temp range */ 
        printf("2nd range Cp= %.6f J/kgK",cp2);                 /* returns cp2 */
    }
    else if (T>646.8 && T<=651.2f) {            /* 3rd temp range*/ 
        printf("3rd range Cp= %.6f J/kgK",cp3);                 /* returns cp3 */
    }
    else if (T>651.2 && T<=655.8) {            /* 4th temp range */ 
        printf("4th range Cp= %.6f J/kgK",cp4);                 /* returns cp4 */
    }
    else if (T>655.8 && T<=656.6) {            /* 5th temp range */ 
        printf("5th range Cp= %.6f J/kgK",cp5);                 /* returns cp5 */
    }
    else if (T>656.6 && T<=662.) {            /* 6th temp range */ 
        printf("6th range Cp= %.6f J/kgK",cp6);                 /* returns cp6 */
    }
    else if (T>662. && T<=700.) {            /* 7th temp range */ 
        printf("7th range Cp= %.6f J/kgK",cp7);                 /* returns cp7 */
    }
    else if (T>700. && T<=900.) {            /* 8th temp range */ 
        printf("8th range Cp= %.6f J/kgK",cp8);                 /* returns cp8 */
    }
    else {
        printf("The value entered is NOT in the 280-900 K range. Default Cp= 4180 J/kgK");     /* Executed if no other statement is */
    }
    printf("\nPress any key to exit.");
    getch();
  return 0;
}
```

density part:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <math.h>

int main()
{    
    float T, rho1, rho2, rho3, rho4, rho5;                     /*variables */  


    printf( "Enter temperature in Kelvin (range 280-900 K)\n" );  /* Asks for temperature */
    scanf( "%f", &T );

    rho1=-0.00000266869827*pow(T,3.)+0.001092981832*pow(T,2.)-0.353045781*T+1087.047262;
    rho2=-0.00003541921142*pow(T,4.)+0.08730402305*pow(T,3.)-80.71356495*pow(T,2.)+33168.28128*T-5110738.52;
    rho3=-0.0133134195680782*pow(T,5.)+43.6908659112031*pow(T,4.)-57351.2250577165*pow(T,3.)+37640535.2854736*pow(T,2.)-12351791332.418*T+1621269348006.22;
    rho4=-3.99858316063595E-06*pow(T,5.)+0.0136859140134915*pow(T,4.)-18.7366565748224*pow(T,3.)+12825.4332022085*pow(T,2.)-4389497.59259435*T+600913288.082835;
    rho5=-0.000006557464349*pow(T,3.)+0.0168728672*pow(T,2.)-14.60996074*T+4327.503734;


    if (T>=280. && T<=599.9f) {                     /* 1st temp range*/ 
        printf ("1st range Rho= %.6f kg/m3",rho1);                  /* returns rho1 */
    }
    else if (T>599.9 && T<=649.9f) {            /* 2nd temp range */ 
        printf("2nd range Rho= %.6f kg/m3",rho2);                   /* returns rho2 */
    }
    else if (T>649.9 && T<=659.8) {            /* 3rd temp range*/ 
        printf("3rd range Rho= %.6f kg/m3",rho3);                   /* returns rho3 */
    }
    else if (T>659.8 && T<=700.) {            /* 4th temp range */ 
        printf("4th range Rho= %.6f kg/m3",rho4);                   /* returns rho4 */
    }
    else if (T>700. && T<=900.) {            /* 5th temp range */ 
        printf("5th range Rho= %.6f kg/m3",rho5);                   /* returns rho5 */
    }

    else {
        printf("The value entered is NOT in the 280-900 K range. Default Rho= 1000 kg/m3");     /* Executed if no other statement is */
    }

    printf("\nPress any key to exit.");
    getch();
  return 0;
}
```

The question is how do I make the four functions and integrate them togheter?
This might be a trivial question but I have zero experience with programming.

Comment: a) Have you ever heard of _functions_ (also known as subroutines, methods, procedures, ...)? b) Copy the code into those places where you need them?

Comment: One source file doesn't necessarily correspond to one `.exe` file. A linker might do the job with some modifications.

Comment: Are you sure you want to have everything in one file? You know you can just compile all those files into one `.exe` when you're using functions, right?

Comment: IMHO, it is time to **spend several days** (or even weeks) **reading and learning more about programming** (e.g. [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/)...). Don't forget to enable all warnings & debug info, so compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Learn how to **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: I remember this OP from yesterday, for clarity he was learning and avoiding using functions. Props to OP for now learning how to use these :). It's definitely worth going and reading a few basic tutorials on functions in C and how they work.

Comment: @MPI_What thank you! time was really pressing me so I had to take the shortcut and ask for help on stackoverflow :). I will definitely continue with tutorials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the source code in functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <math.h>

// The following line defines a function
void specific_heat(){
    // Copy contents of the first main() here
}

void density(){
    // Copy contents of the second main() here
}

int main(){
    // Ask for choice here

    if (choice == 1)
    {
        // The following line executes a function
        specific_heat();
    }

    if (choice == 2)
    {
        density();
    }
}
```